# What is the difference between saving web page info with Python program(urllib, request) and save through browser

Tags: python, html, url, urllib2

Span class names and div class information of HTML page is missing when i am trying to open the Web page with the python program. I have tried urllib.request.urlopen() , requests.get(), wget, robobrowser and some other packages in saving the web page with data of class names,but not succeeded.

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Navallur,+Tamil+Nadu+600130/Vijayawada,+Andhra+Pradesh/@14.6711659,78.0012123,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x3a525a51439fd9f3:0x5fdacd19ed90126c!2m2!1d80.225463!2d12.8447728!1m5!1m1!1s0x3a35eff9482d944b:0x939b7e84ab4a0265!2m2!1d80.6480153!2d16.5061743'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
page1 = requests.get(url).content

html = open('some1.html','wb')
html.write(page)
html.close()
```

Comment: Some websites don't load all the content immediately and require the user to interact with the page through a browser (or headless browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium package in Python allows you to do the task Naga :-)

```
from selenium import webdriver

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get(URL)
html = ff.page_sources
```